# Como puedo ingresar una opcion de un menu dentro de dos corchetes como estos [ ]? en c++

Tags: c++, dev-c++, visual-c++

hola buenas soy algo novata en c++ y probando cosas me gustaría saber como podría yo crear un menú y que al ingresar la opción se pueda ingresar así

ingrese su opción[] entonces yo ingreso el numero dentro de los corchetes, como podría hacer eso me ayudarían?

```
char* tipopersona[]={"Persionado(65 años en adelante)","Niño(a)(0-11 años),Adolecente(12-17 años)",
     "Adulto (de 18 años en adelante antes de los 65 años)","Discapacidad"};

     for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
        cout<<"["<<i+1<<"] - "<<tipopersona[i]<<endl;
    }
    cout<<"Ingrese la opcion [ ]"<<endl;
    cin>>tipo2;
```

les pongo este codigo como ejemplo

Comment: No entiendo muy bien tu pregunta, lo que quieres es usar `tipo2` para seleccionar con ese indice lo que se encuentra dentro de `tipopersona` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es mover el cursor dentro de la terminal, lo que puedes hacer
es utilizar los [códigos de escape
ANSI](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%B3digo_escape_ANSI).

Aquí tienes un ejemplo implementando el comportamiento que comentabas.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#ifdef _WIN32
    // https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences
    #include <Windows.h>

    bool EnableVTMode() {
        // Set output mode to handle virtual terminal sequences
        HANDLE hOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
        if (hOut == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
            return false;
        }
    
        DWORD dwMode = 0;
        if (!GetConsoleMode(hOut, &dwMode)) {
            return false;
        }
    
        dwMode |= ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING;
        return SetConsoleMode(hOut, dwMode) != 0;
    }

#endif

int main() {
    #ifdef _WIN32
        EnableVTMode();
    #endif

    int opcion = 0;

    std::string prompt = "Ingrese una opcion: [ ]";
    std::cout << prompt;

    // El codigo de escape ESC[<n>G Mueve el cursor a la posicion indicada
    // en la misma linea
    std::cout << "\x01B[" << prompt.size() - 1 << 'G';

    std::cin >> opcion;

    std::cout << "Ingreso: " << opcion;
    return 0;
}
```

El resultado sera:

```
Ingrese una opcion: [ ]
                     ^
                     |
           El cursor estara aqui
```

Comment: También puede considerar usar `SetConsoleCursorPosition` si no tiene conocimiento de los caracteres de control. (Para Windows)

Comment: Si es cierto, es una muy buena opción también. Yo suelo recomendar los caracteres de escape porque funcionan en todos lados. En mac y linux de default, y en Windows luego de activarlos manualmente. @Mateo

Comment: Entonces no estaría mal agregar un `#ifdef _WIN32` si el caso es que sea multiplataforma.

Comment: @Mateo Supongo que si. Gracias por la nota, ahora lo agrego

Comment: aja si esto mismo es lo que queria saber como hacer, que el cursor quedara dentro de los [ ]